# Error C2065 'IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, com

Here's a MS official example of [how to use MSXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766451(v=vs.85))

```
void AddCollectionSample()  
{  
    IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr pIXMLDOMDocument2;  
    IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2Ptr pIXMLDOMSchemaCollection2Ptr; 
   ...
}
```

The code is simple, but doesn't compile on my Visual Studio 2019 with the error can't find the declaration of IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr.

I've already included these headers and lib.

```
#include "msxml2.h"  
#include "msxml6.h"  
#pragma comment(lib, "msxml6.lib")
```

I searched this `IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr` online and found out it's supposed to be under MSXML2 (a namespace). But my project doesn't recognize this namespace as well. Then I found it, you have to import this library,`#import <msxml6.dll>`

[image]

But this is supposed to be for C#. How about my C++ project?

Edit:
I find this,
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43309/How-to-create-a-simple-XML-file-using-MSXML-in-C

The first thing you need to do is add these two lines in the project stdafx.h file:

```
#import "MSXML4.dll" rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))
#include <msxml2.h>
```

I modified this `MSXML4.dll` to my newly `MSXML6.dll`, but the project can't find it still.

Comment: Wild guess: you're probably missing a "using namespace xmlsomething;"

Comment: The code in the example snippet does not appear to be correct.  You should use #import but *not* #include.  The #import generates a msxml6.tlh file from the type library embedded in msxml6.dll that should have all the declarations you need.

Answer (score 2):

The sample code is using [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class), a COM smart pointer class template provided by Visual Studio. Yet the code provided is incomplete.

To declare a `_com_ptr_t` specialization for any given interface you would usually use the `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` macro. In this case the following declarations need to be added:

```cpp
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMDocument2, __uuidof(IXMLDOMDocument2));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2, __uuidof(IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2));
```

This declares the types `IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr` and `IXMLDOMSchemaCollection2Ptr` as specializations of `_com_ptr_t`, ready to be used. You'll need to `#include <comip.h>`, too.

An alternative would be to use the compiler specific [`#import` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp). This generates header files from a type library (TLB), and by default includes the respective `_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF` declarations (see [Primary type library header file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp#_predir_the_primary_type_library_header_file)).

Answer (score -1):

From this [demo](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43309/How-to-create-a-simple-XML-file-using-MSXML-in-C)
The first thing you need to do is add these two lines in the project stdafx.h file:

```
#import "MSXML6.dll" rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))
#include <msxml2.h>
```

Then correct all the `MSXML2` to `MSXML`, as we specified the name `rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))`.

I didn't bother to do this, I at first tried `namespace MSXML2=MSXML` didn't work. So I just defined a MACRO `#define MSXML2 MSXML`. It compiled!